# Display Sharepoint list data in Dropdown format

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am calling a Sharepoint URL (GET) and retriving the column information. I have column names like **First Name** (eg Donald), **Last Name** (eg Duck), etc in the list.
Now I have to concat First Name & Last Name (Donald Duck) and to display this in form of a dropdown list. I am writing the below piece of code to get the shareopint response (XML):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password)); }, 
    url: calURL,
 crossDomain: true,
    //dataType: "xml",
 //cache: false,
    processData: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
 alert(errorThrown); 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Got stuck";
 },
    success: function(xml) { 

 var xmlArr = [];
 var html_text = null;
 alert($(xml).find('entry').text());
 $(xml).find('entry').each(function(){

  var title = $(this).find('title').text();
  var firstName = $(this).find('First Name').text();
  var familyName = $(this).find('Family Name').text();
  var fullName = title + firstName + familyName;
    });
 
 },
});
```

However, the above is not reading the values from the response. And also how can i convert this into a dropdown in the HTML page?
Thanks.

Comment: I can see in the alert that title is getting filled. However there is a problem with First Name and Last Name

Comment: You should check the column names in response. Normally, it will internally name and encode as "First_x0020_Name"

Comment: Thanks
I get the internal name as Family%5Fx0020%5FName in the Sharepoint list. However when I use this in the Javascript i get "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Family%5Fx0020%5FName" error. Do you know how can I check what column names are coming in the response?

Comment: I do not get the names when I do an alert on the incoming response --> alert($(xml).find('entry').text());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided your SharePoint response XML, but the information you want are most likely to be in the row element `attributes` rather than in their `text` content. Moreover every element in this xml has a namespace which should be referenced.

#### A sample XML:

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
     xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
     xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"> 

      <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema"> 
        <s:ElementType name="row"> 
          <s:AttributeType name="CustomerID" rs:number="1" rs:keycolumn="true"> 
            <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4"/> 
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:AttributeType name="Title" rs:number="2"> 
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="5" /> 
          </s:AttributeType>
          <s:AttributeType name="FirstName" rs:number="3"> 
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="15" /> 
          </s:AttributeType> 
          <s:AttributeType name="LastName" rs:number="4"> 
            <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="15"/> 
          </s:AttributeType> 
        </s:ElementType> 
      </s:Schema> 

      <rs:data> 
        <z:row CustomerID="123" Title="Mr."  FirstName="Donald" LastName="Duck"/> 
        <z:row CustomerID="456" Title="Mrs." FirstName="Minney" LastName="Mouse"/> 
        <z:row CustomerID="789" Title="Mr."  FirstName="Stuart" LastName="Little"/> 
      </rs:data> 
</xml>
```

If your response XML is like something above, change the ajax success handler to

```
success: function(xml) { 
    $("rs\\:data", xml).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('CustomerID');
        var title = $(this).attr('Title');
        var firstName = $(this).attr('FirstName');
        var lastName = $(this).attr('LastName');
        var fullName = title + firstName + lastName;
        // Add this as an option to <select id="customers"> dropdown list
        var option = '<option value="' + id + '">' + fullName + '</option>';
        $("#customers").append(option);
    });
}
```

Comment: '<xml>
      <rs:data>
 <records>
          <z:row CustomerID="123" Title="Mr."  FirstName="Donald" LastName="Duck"/> 
          <z:row CustomerID="456" Title="Mrs." FirstName="Minney" LastName="Mouse"/> 
          <z:row CustomerID="789" Title="Mr."  FirstName="Stuart" LastName="Little"/> 
 </records>
      </rs:data> 
</xml>'

Comment: This is an invalid XML, I don't think SharePoint would generate this. You will need the namespaces defined for `rs:` and `z:` in the <xml> tag. Otherwise, remove `rs:` from `<rs:data>` element and `z:` from every `<z:row>` element (also change line `$("rs\\:data", xml).find("z\\:row").each(function() {` to `$("data", xml).find("row").each(function() {`